# How to query a nested tuple by index using a list to represent the index?

Tags: python, tuples

Get the value of a nested tuple at certain index like so:

```
tup = ((-3, (6, 15), 3), -9, ((-3, -6, 9, -5), -2))
    
print(tup[0][1][1])
>> 15
```

Want to query a nested tuple by index using as a list to represent the index, something like:

```
def getTupValue(input_tuple, input_list=[])
    ## returns the value at for example: tup[0][1][1]

getTupValue(tup, [0, 1, 1])
## returns 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that there won't be index errors, you can simply do:

```
def get_by_indexes(tup, indexes):
    for index in indexes:
        tup = tup[index]
    return tup


mytuple = ((-3, (6, 15), 3), -9, ((-3, -6, 9, -5), -2))
print(get_by_indexes(mytuple, [0, 1, 1]))
```

**Output:**

```
15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```py
from functools import reduce

tup = ((-3, (6, 15), 3), -9, ((-3, -6, 9, -5), -2))


def getTupValue(input_tuple, input_list):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], input_list, input_tuple)


print(getTupValue(tup, [0, 1, 1]))
```

Prints:

```
15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getTupValue(input_tuple, input_list: list=None):
    if input_list in [None, []]:
        return input_tuple
    return getTupValue(input_tuple[input_list.pop(0)], input_list)
tup = ((-3, (6, 15), 3), -9, ((-3, -6, 9, -5), -2))
getTupValue(tup, input_list=[0,1,1])
```